# Is it possible to echo a woocommerce prouct attribute discription?

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, themes

Rather than displaying the attribute name I would like to display it's description. Is this possible?

```
function woo_specifications_product_tab_content() {

// The new tab content
global $product;
echo '<h2>Specifications</h2>';
echo $product->get_description();
echo $product->get_attribute( 'colour-code' ); ///I WANT THE COLOUR-CODE DESCRIPTION RATHER THAN THE JUST THE COLOUR CODE. 
}
```

[image: Description I would like to echo]

Comment: It looks like it’s storing them as a taxonomy. Try [get_term_by](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)?

Comment: You're not using attributes as intended. What you have as a _Description_ should be the _Name_. If you're placing numeric codes as _Name_ so that you can mention them easily in the code, that's what _Slug_ is for. For example, instead of `$product->get_attribute( '02' );` to get the 'Blue' attribute, you would get it with `$product->get_attribute( 'blue' );`

Comment: I am importing colour codes and I need to convert them to Text. So The names can't change they have to stay a numerical values.